# Inplace add with list selectors

Tags: python, pytorch, in-place

I'm facing a somehow inconsistent behaviour of pythorch according to weither the index is a list or an integer. Take a look at this snippet of code :

```
# First example, integer selector ==> Ok
t = torch.tensor([[0, 1], [1, 0]])
t[0, 0].add_(10)
print(t)
tensor([[10,  1],
        [ 1,  0]])

# Second example, list selector ==> ???
t = torch.tensor([[0, 1], [1, 0]])
t[[0], [0]].add_(10) # notice the list selector
print(t)
tensor([[0, 1],
        [1, 0]])

#Third example, list selector with inplace add operator ==> Ok
t = torch.tensor([[0, 1], [1, 0]])
t[[0], [0]] += 10
print(t)
tensor([[10,  1],
        [ 1,  0]])
```

I can't understand why `pytorch` was unable to update `t`in the second example !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the difference between the two indexing:

```
In []: t[0, 0].shape
```

> ```
> Out[]: torch.Size([])
> ```

```
In []: t[[0], [0]].shape
```

> ```
> Out[]: torch.Size([1])
> ```

When you index directly the `(0, 0)`th element of `t` you have a reference to that entry and you can inplace `add_` to it. The shape of `t[0,0]` is `[]` - that is you get a scalar back - the content of the `(0,0)` entry.
However, when you use list indices `([0], [0])` you get back a 1-dim tensor, shape is `[1]`. That is, you get a *copy* of a sub-tensor of `t`. You then inplace `add_` to that copy of sub-tensor, you have no effect over the original `t`:

```py
In []: r = t[[0], [0]].add_(10)
In []: t
Out[]:
tensor([[0, 1],
        [1, 0]])

In []: r
Out[]: tensor([10])
```

Perhaps you want to look into [`index_add_()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.index_add_) to accomplish your task.

**Update** 
When you assign to `t` using list indices, you are not creating a copy (it makes no sense. So,

```py
t[[0], [0]] += 10
```

Translates to

```py
t[[0], [0]] = t[[0], [0]] + 10
```

That is, on the right hand side we have a *copy* of the `(0,0)` sub-tensor of `t` and we are adding 10 to that sub-tensor, resulting with a shape `[1]` tensor with value `[10]`. On the left hand side we assign this `[10]` to the `(0,0)` sub-tensor of `t` (not to a copy of it - it makes no sense).
Therefore the output of `t[[0], [0]] += 10` is

```py
tensor([[10,  1],
        [ 1,  0]])
```

Comment: To clarify, I guess the shape of the returned tensor here is irrelevant, zero-dim tensors can be views or copies too. The point is that list indexing returns a copy, and `add_` is called on that copy in the question.

Comment: I could accept your answer if not because of the third example (see the edited question). How was that possible if t[[0], [0]] is just a copy from `t` ?

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Shai

Answer (score 2):

That's because fancy indexing (i.e using lists to index) returns a copy, while direct indexing returns a view to the original tensor. An easy way to check this is the case is to compare the underlying [storage](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/storage.html#torch-storage)

```
In [16]: a = torch.arange(3)

In [17]: a.storage()
Out[17]:
 0
 1
 2
[torch.LongStorage of size 3]

In [18]: a[0].storage()
Out[18]:
 0
 1
 2
[torch.LongStorage of size 3]

In [19]: a[[0]].storage()
Out[19]:
 0
[torch.LongStorage of size 1]
```

Note how `a[0]` is a single element, but it's storage is still the full array, since it is only a view of the original tensor.

Comment: I could accept your answer if not because of the third example (see the edited question). How was that possible if `t[[0], [0]]` is just a copy from t ?